# UIBarButtonItem - Change Background image programmatically

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, image, uibarbuttonitem

How can I change the background image of an **UIBarButtonItem** programmatically?

Answer (score 4):

```
[yourbarButtonItem setBackButtonBackgroundImage:bckgrndImag forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:0];
```

Details:

```
setBackButtonBackgroundImage:forState:barMetrics:
```

Sets the back button background image for a given control state and bar metrics

```
- (void)setBackButtonBackgroundImage:(UIImage *)backgroundImage forState:(UIControlState)state barMetrics:(UIBarMetrics)barMetrics
```

**Parameters:**

```
backgroundImage
```

The image to use for the back button’s background.

```
state
```

A control state.

```
barMetrics
```

Bar metrics.

**Discussion**

This modifier applies only to navigation bar back buttons and is ignored by other buttons.

For good results, backgroundImage must be a stretchable image.

**Availability**

Available in iOS 5.0 and later.

**See Also**

```
– backButtonBackgroundImageForState:barMetrics:
– setBackButtonBackgroundVerticalPositionAdjustment:forBarMetrics:
```

**Declared In**

```
UIBarButtonItem.h
```

Answer (score -2):

Try just this:

```
[yourButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"MY_IMAGE"] forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault]
```

Change `MY_IMAGE` to your desired background image and for the `forState` argument, change it to whichever you want: normal, selected, disabled, etc.